# Post list from editorfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

I have a view that iterates over a model list and calls editorfor for each model in the list.  The list is simply a row of data that can be modified.  How do I in turn post this list back to the controller with the changes that are made?  The main view is:

```
 @model List<Program.Models.Model>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "DPR";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDpr", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formDPR"}))
{
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="displaybutton" onclick="CreateDPR();">Create DPR</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="background-color:white">
    <table style="font-size:xx-small" class="table_body">
        <caption style="font-size:medium;font-weight:bold">Patients For DPR</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color:lightgray">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Last Review</th>
                <th>Include?</th>
                <th>Reason</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.EditorFor(m=>Model[i])
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div>

</div>
}
```

JS Function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#formDPR").serializeArray(),
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateDpr")',
        success: function (data) {
            var test = data;
        }
    });
    return false;
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateDpr(List<Model> models)
    {
        var pats = models;
        return Json("DONE");
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code from the View, Model and Controller?

Comment: @Kevin - I've posted some of the code.

Comment: Try to change the data value from serializeArray() to serialize()

Comment: Do you have to use Ajax to do the post?

Comment: Firstly, you don't need a loop in the view. Its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)`. Then its `data: $("#formDPR").serialize(),` in the script